# "Monitorando" uso de aplicativos

Tags: android, app

- Há alguma maneira de de monitorar quanto tempo o usuário usa cada aplicativo?
- O Google Analytics tem a capacidade de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, existe essa possibilidade. O Google Analytics te dá o tempo médio das sessões de uso. Há ainda a feature de "ao vivo", onde você consegue ver quem está utilizando o aplicativo no momento.

Comment: existe alguma documentação alem dessa? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html

Comment: Sim: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/